Scratch on a Canadian passport
I am Canadian-Polish citizen, and on 1st of June I am flying to Canada via Stockholm to visit my family.
I have noticed a small scratch on my Canadian passport from someone putting a luggage tag on my 3rd passport page...
Just wanted to ask if this will be bad for the airline or Canadian border (I also have my polish passport, but need to use Canadian one as dual citizen).


I would be extremely surprised if this caused you any trouble. The passport is holding together and everything is readable. I traveled for years with a much more damaged Canadian passport then this, although also still readable and intact. I got told a few times I needed to replace it, which I eventually did, but I was never refused boarding or entry.
Use the passport, and replace it if anybody says you should. Perhaps ask the next immigration official you show it to if it's not too busy.

Thanks, i was just too panicking. My friend also told me that Canada cannot deny entry its own citizen, so even airport staff should know this. Hopefully they are right. Also 99% of the passport including bio and visa pages are perfect.

@Kokoapropp I do understand that they deny entry to Canadian citizens entering by air with dual nationality if their Canadian passport is not valid, so assuming that it hasn’t expired you should be ok.

@John not having a valid Canadian passport is not by itself sufficient reason to deny entry.

@Kokoapropp airport staff operate under different requirements from border officers.  The airline can be fined a few thousand dollars for transporting a passenger with inadequate documents, so they will not risk it.  If you show up, for example, with an expired Canadian passport and a valid Polish passport without eTA then you will most likely not receive a boarding pass even though a border officer would probably admit you as a Canadian citizen with those documents.

@phoog Maybe not, but you generally (you might get a one off emergency travel exemption) won't get an ETA without having a valid Canadian passport and without one of those, as you say above, you're very likely not going to be getting on the plane.

No , I don't think this should cause any trouble because the tampered part is not going inside the passport reader machine. The problem (minor or major) can occur only when the area shown in the image below gets corrupted/damaged/tampered, none of them seems to be the case in your case. In another cases, the problem can also occur if the visa sticker is bad because sometimes the visa sticker also has some hidden security features.


Thanks. The rest of the passport including Bio,photo Visa page is almost brand new condition. Also I think that Canada would not deny entry its own citizen.

It is not only damaged security features that can cause problems.  If the passport appears to have been materially altered or otherwise tampered with then it is not likely to be accepted, regardless of the impact on security features.  If part of any page is cut off, the passport would be likely to be unacceptable to any border officer who noticed it, even a page such as the one shown here, which is neither a visa page nor the machine-readable data page.

@phoog Even if the Bio page, and visa pages are perfect condition, and also I can show the airline staff my 2nd Polish passport + Canadian citizenship card they still would make problems about it? They must be very picky, because they have to know that Canadian border wont turn back their citizen from border. So the worst part will be to convince the airline worker that I can enter Canada and the passport is ok.
